# Huge speed difference in two similar queries (MySQL ORDER clause)

Tags: mysql, sql

**Important updade (explanation):**
I realized that my query having single DESC order is 10 times slower that the same query with ASC order. The ordered field has an index. Is it normal behavior?

**Original question with queries:**

I have a mysql table with a few hundred of product items. It's suprising (for me) how 2 similar sql queries differs in terms of performance. I don't know why. Can you please give me a hint or explain why the difference is so huge?

**This query takes 3ms:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `product_items`
WHERE
    (product_items.shop_active = 1)
    AND (product_items.active = 1)
    AND (product_items.active_category_id is not null)
    AND (has_picture is not null)
    AND (price_orig is not null)
    AND (category_min_discount IS NOT NULL)
    AND (product_items.slug is not null)
    AND `product_items`.`active_category_id` IN (6797, 5926, 5806, 6852)
ORDER BY
    price asc
LIMIT 1
```

**But the following query takes already 169ms...** Only difference is that the order clause contains 2 columns. "Price" value has each product, while "price top" has roughly only 1% of products.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `product_items`
WHERE
    (product_items.shop_active = 1)
    AND (product_items.active = 1)
    AND (product_items.active_category_id is not null)
    AND (has_picture is not null)
    AND (price_orig is not null)
    AND (category_min_discount IS NOT NULL)
    AND (product_items.slug is not null)
    AND `product_items`.`active_category_id` IN (6797, 5926, 5806, 6852)
ORDER BY
    price asc,
    price_top desc
LIMIT 1
```

The table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shop_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `url` text,
  `url_hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img_url` text,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_orig` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_percent` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categorytext` text,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `price_top` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `attention_priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attention_priority_over` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_picture` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_min_discount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_product_items_on_url_hash` (`url_hash`),
  KEY `index_product_items_on_shop_id` (`shop_id`),
  KEY `index_product_items_on_active_category_id` (`active_category_id`),
  KEY `index_product_items_on_productname` (`productname`),
  KEY `index_product_items_on_price` (`price`),
  KEY `index_product_items_on_discount_percent` (`discount_percent`),
  KEY `index_product_items_on_price_top` (`price_top`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1715708 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**UPDATE**
I realized that the difference is mainly in the type of ordering: if I use asc+asc for both columns the query takes around 6ms, if I use asc+desc or desc+asc, the query takes around 160ms..

Thank you.

Comment: Post the query plan,m for each, we can't do anywhere near as much without it

Comment: @CaiusJard   .. have you obtained  the raise ??? :)..

Answer (score 0):

If creating an index to help ORDER BY doesn't help, try creating an index that helps both WHERE and ORDER BY:

```
CREATE INDEX product_items_i1 ON product_items (
    shop_active,
    active,
    active_category_id,
    has_picture,
    price_orig,
    category_min_discount,
    slug,
    price,
    price_top DESC
)
```

Obviously, this is a bit clunky, and you'll have to balance the performance gain for the query with the price of maintaining the index.